# Writing to buffer vs writing directly to file

Tags: c, file-io

I have a program that gets content from the internet and saves it to a file, then goes to another page and appends its content to the same file, looping until a condition is met.

Would it be faster if the program put the contents into a buffer and only saved to the file when the buffer is full?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Storing them in buffer and flushing the buffer to full when full will be a better approach. Because buffer is stored in RAM where as the files are stored on hard drive. This is the reason most of the programming languages have buffered readers and writers.

However it again depends on how you implement the buffer as well.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer